# HTML/CSS Entire div not appearing

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with a site that I'm rebuilding. I'm quite new to HTML/CSS, for some reason this entire div is not appearing.

This is the div that isn't working.

```
<div class="container clearfix">
    <div class="border-shade slide0">
      <h1 id="logo"> <a href="index.31.html" webstripperwas="index.html">PPC Mint</a> </h1>
      <div class="col1-1">
        <h3>The <span>forward-thinking</span>  PPC and CRO firm that delivers a high and consistent ROI to a broad range of clients. That’s it. Simple.  <br>
          </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="big-break"></div>
    <div class="col1-2 slide1"><a href="#">
      <div class="images">
        <div class="img-wrap"><img src="images/photodune-3551394_col1-2.jpg" webstripperwas="images/photodune-3551394_col1-2.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="infos"></div>
      </div>
      </a></div>
    <div class="col1-4 slide2"><a href="#">
      <div class="images">
        <div class="img-wrap"><img src="images/shutterstock_96093131.jpg" webstripperwas="images/shutterstock_96093131.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="infos"></div>
      </div>
      </a></div>
    <div class="col1-4 slide3"><a href="#">
      <div class="images">
        <div class="img-wrap"><img src="images/photodune-3550538.jpg" webstripperwas="images/photodune-3550538.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="infos"></div>
      </div>
      </a></div>
    <div class="col1-3 slide4"><a href="#">
      <div class="images">
        <div class="img-wrap"><img src="images/photodune-3551521.jpg" webstripperwas="images/photodune-3551521.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="infos"></div>
      </div>
      </a></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
```

I only found people suggesting that there might be some invalid code in my css, like I have a space somewhere that I shouldn't. I believe that this is valid html (I don't think I'm missing any html tags).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please post corresponding CSS code.

Comment: added corresponding css code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `slideX` (*`slide0`, `slide1`, etc*) on the child divs

These classes have `opacity:0` .. so nothing shows..

Comment: Fixed, thanks a lot. Can I just ask, is there a better setting than opacity:1 for this?

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
.slide0, .slide1, .slide2, .slide3, .slide4 {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

on line 92 of styles.css.
Remove it and it will work.